# How to download artifacts from other (private) repo?

Tags: github-actions

I have private repo A (which is a library) and that repo has releases. Now I have repo B which has a dependency on the artifacts of A. The dependency (i.e. which version) is stored in a json file in B. What I'm looking for is a way to download the artifacts of release X from repo A in an action/workflow in repo B.

I have seen a lengthy bash script which make this possible, but I'm wondering if there are off the shelf actions around.

Comment: Do you have credentials to access the other private repo? If yes, you can use many different tools to download a package via its URL.

Comment: Yes, I do have the credentials. I'm aware of (a series of ) curl/wget commands. Are there other tools?

Comment: Do you mean tools like **curl** or **wget**? Edit your question to clarify what you are asking. Writing software to look up and download a package is fairly simple to complete.

Comment: Would it be an option to copy the artifacts from A to B through your workflow?

Comment: I got it to work with 2 curl commands where the first fetches (among other data) the asset id of what I need and the second curl uses that asset id that download the actual asset. It's all a bit verbose.

Comment: @JohnHanley in my original question I'm asking if there's a Github action available. I think that's specific enough.

Comment: Your question is not clear, that is why I asked. Perhaps investing more time in your question will help get an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Github actions are pretty well defined and exactly what I’m asking. What is it that you don’t understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Linux runner, you can use the [Fetch Github Release Asset](https://github.com/dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset) action.

```
uses: dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset@master
with:
  repo: "user/repo"
  version: "tags/v1"
  file: "filename.ext"
  target: "targetFolder/targetFileName.ext"
  token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TO_ACCESS_PRIVATE_REPO }}
```

> ### Inputs
>
> **`token`**
>
> Required The GitHub token. Typically this will be ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
>
> **`file`**
>
> Required The name of the file to be downloaded.
>
> **`repo`**
>
> The org/repo containing the release. Defaults to the current repo.
>
> **`version`**
>
> The release version to fetch from in the form tags/<tag_name> or <release_id>. Defaults to latest.
>
> **`target`**
>
> Target file path. Only supports paths to subdirectories of the GitHub Actions workspace directory

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @BroncoOostermeyer please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. It signals others that this is solved. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.